# Supabase SELECT with function call

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

From Javascript, I want to call a function in my supabase select statement (funcition name is `id_encode` in this example):

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('table')
        .select("id, id_encode(id, 'salt', 8)")
```

equivalent in SQL would be:

```
SELECT id, id_encode(id, 'salt', 8) FROM table;
```

Comment: Alternatively, I could add a column to the table, so long as it's default value is `id_encode(id)` somehow.

Comment: I ended up creating a `short_id` column that auto-populates with a trigger on insert. Prolly better in the long run for my application. But I'd still like to know if the above question has an answer.